# JQuery.ajax() loading XML file coming in blank with no errors.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

Ok so I have been sitting here staring at my screen for hours and something just isn't working so I had to ask.

I have an XML file that follows this format:

```
<news attribs="thedate,image,thetext">
    <item thedate="<redacted>" image="<redacted>"><![CDATA[<redacted>]]></item>
    ...
</news>
```

and here is my JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "news.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        console.log(xml);
        $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
            var date, image, text;
            date  = this.thedate;
            image = this.image;
            text  = this.text();

            console.log(date, image, text);
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("An error occurred while processing the XML file.");
    }
```

Right now I am literally just trying to get the XML file to load in. I have been working on this for a few hours at work and I have hit a wall and I feel like I'm just missing an obvious error somewhere.The `console.log(xml);` doesn't post anything to the console which makes me think the file just isn't loading in but it stopped giving me an error so I have NO IDEA.

Side question: I am also not sure about the format for getting the attributes but I need to fix the xml loading before I can even touch that.

Comment: Can you please provide any fiddle with LIVE code?

Comment: `console.log('Result:', xml)` would make it pretty clear whether or not it's getting to success or the xml is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :
    error: function (xhr,err){
    alert(err);
    }
And when you know what's exactly the error, deal with it.

Comment: There was an error inside the XML file that I found because of this answer so thank you! There were &'s used throughout and it was throwing errors, ended up replacing them with "&amp;".